# CSS not loading in newly Yii2 basic application in virtual host

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Just installed XAMPP and downloaded the basic version of Yii2. I was getting problem in loading the CSS in virtual host.

When I tried *http://localhost:8080/danish/web/index.php*, page is loading CSS and all.

[image]

And, when I tried *http://danish.local:8080/*, page is not loading CSS

[image]

I checked the page source as well.

**Page Source localhost:8080**

[image]

**Page Source Virtual Host (danish.local:8080)**

[image]

File: **/assets/AppAsset.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap5\BootstrapAsset'
    ];
}
```

File: **/config/web.php**

```
<?php

$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => \yii\symfonymailer\Mailer::class,
            'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\web\index.php"
    ServerName danish.local
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       danish.local
```

What I need to do to load CSS in newly setup. Any help/hint/suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Open DevTools and Network tab, check what actual URL is loaded. If URL seems _ok_, than ensure it's reachable (simply open that URL in browser, debug till fixed)

Comment: `DocumentRoot` in Apache should be a directory/folder, not a `.php` file. Did you check their [Recommended Apache Configuration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#recommended-apache-configuration)?

Comment: can you try change 'baseUrl' => '/' in web.php

Comment: I met this prb before, try to add  to the `components> request>` property: `'baseUrl' => ''`

Comment: @DarkShade As i remember , if you add `/` it will brake all the css and url rules as well.